# What is "1#" in rfc2616

Tags: http, rfc2616

I'm reading the http standard in [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26).
Now I want to get the format of `If-None-Match`. It gives me:

> If-None-Match = "If-None-Match" ":" ( "*" | 1#entity-tag )

What is the `1#` ? Or dose `1#entity-tag` means the exact of `ETag` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means 1 or more occurrences of "entity-tag".

The syntax is explained in the RFC, in section 2.1, "Augmented BNF":

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.1

**Important note**: RFC 2616 is obsolete. It's been superseded by a series of 6 RFCs: 7230, 7231, 7232, 7233, 7234, 7235. See https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead

Comment: Right, but the correct spec to look at is <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#abnf.extension>